# iPad 3 and NSUserDefaults problems

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have had a couple of apps that are approved and available in iTunes. I tested them on an iPad 2 with iOS 5.0. They are some features that are unlocked through in-app purchases in those apps. Once the user successfully buys a certain feature, I check to make sure the transaction was successful and i unlock it by setting a NSUserDefaults variable.

Recently some of my iPad 3 users have been complaining that they buy a feature and it is still unlocked. I don't own iPad 3 so I tested the released code on iPad 2 and it works just fine.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue with iPad 3? Is there some bug or problem with NSUserDefaults in iOS 5.1?

Here is the code

```
NSArray *stringsArray2a = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stringsArray2a forKey:@"MyAppWeatherPackStr"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then I check for it like this

```
     NSArray *purchasedAppArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAppWeatherPackStr"];
        NSString *purchasedAppStr = [purchasedAppArray objectAtIndex:0];

if([purchasedAppStr isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        //all good keep checking weather

    }
    else
{
//can't check weather
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Does the array ever contain more than one string?

Comment: no, it always contains one string. Here's a thing, the code is not the problem here. If it was I won't be able to successfully test in on iPAD 2 running iOS 5.0. So it gotta be something in iOS 5.1? Though I don't know. If there was a problem there would have been an uproar by now.

Comment: Are you sure customers on iPad 2 have purchased the component?

Comment: I would recommend to check the code that actually calls the 3 lines that save to NSUserDefaults. The NSUserDefaults code is probably not your problem, maybe the receipt validation is.

Comment: Thanks Matt, will check again. Just wish I could afford to buy iPAD 3 to test it out. Simulator is great and all but its not like the real thing.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978852/storing-in-app-purchase-receipts-in-the-application-keychain) for how to store that in the Keychain.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see the point of syncing but a better alternative NSUserDefaults is:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:forKey stringsArray2a:@"1"];
```

I'm not sure were the problem is with NSUser defaults as I'm not fortunate enough to have an iPad 3.

A good idea is to **NOT** store in-app purchase data in NSUserDefaults as you can just mod the plist file to look like you bought it...

Comment: How can you just modify the plist?

Comment: What does that code actually do? Where is the method `setObject:stringsArray2a:` coming from?

Comment: Jailbroken phoned can simply modify the user defaults plist since it is stored in plaintext.

Comment: @borrrden If the user has Jailbroken their phone the likelihood is they are the type of customer who is not going to pay anyway - therefore they are not your customers

Comment: That is a bit of a bold statement, jailbreaking does not make you a bad person, but I will not flood your question with an ethical debate.  I just wanted to point out a technical way.

Comment: Paul.s is saying that if a user is willing to change a plist to not pay for an in-app purchase, not using that plist isn't going to stop them from getting the app extras without paying anyway.

Comment: The point of syncing is to commit the changes to the PList right then.  This is a good habit to get into, as those changes are not committed right away.

Comment: Any ways for the topic using an SQL database will fend off any non experts. Also using MySql would fix your NSUserDefaults problem.

Comment: Wow, this topic went way off fast.