# How do I protect in app purchase content?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure way to unlock full version via In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138730/secure-way-to-unlock-full-version-via-in-app-purchase)

What is the recommended way to protect content which has been downloaded following an in-app purchase from being copied to another device? The typical process seems to be copy the content to the 'Application Support' folder and set a flag in the NSUserDefaults.  Both of these could be updated by someone accessing the iOS device via Finder or similar.  If I store the transaction receipt, that could also be copied across.

I can potentially use the restoreTransactions functionality to validate when the device is online, but that requires the user to enter their password, so it isn't a silent background check and obviously wouldn't work if the device is offline.

I'm tempted to use a device ID to tie the content to the device when it is downloaded, but Apple advise against using this.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned saving it the state in the `NSUserDefaults` is easily edited, but save the state in the KeyChain makes it harder for the user to change the flag state for a download.

I save all my IAP download state in the KeyChain, there by make sure that you can't just set the key to true in `NSUserDefaults`.

In a game we developed we also check server side if the user has bought the game item (also including the recept checking).

In a reader we made the PDF is password protected, via a sort of random code based on the name plus some secret stuff ;)

My guesses are that this should make you are less easy to crack, just keep in mind that you can't also keep a head of the crackers. But you can definitely slow them down.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't looked at KeyChain, so I'll do that